# rails/minitest don't load fixtures for select tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest, fixtures

My tests are written using fixtures and I am slowly refactoring them to use factories instead.

Once I've refactored a test class to not use fixtures I want to not load fixtures for that class. Is there a way to do this? Or am I stuck with either loading them for everything or nothing?

For context, here is how my fixtures are set up now:

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
   Rake::Task["db:fixtures:load"].execute
   ...
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to selectively load fixtures for a test case like this:

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.create_fixtures('test/fixtures', %w[units owners guests])
  ...
end
```

Comment: thanks for this! I have long moved on from this project and don't have time to verify that it works right now. If someone else having this question wants to verify it worked for them I will approve.

Comment: This worked for me, @stoebelj!

Answer (score 8):

Put fixtures in `test/fixtures/users.yml`

Then you are able to include them where you need, for example in `spec_helper`

```
# spec_helper.rb
fixtures :all   # include all fixtures
fixtures :users # include only specific fixtures
```

[Doc: fixtures method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/TestFixtures/ClassMethods.html#method-i-fixtures)

P.S. it works well together with FactoryBot gem (ex. FactoryGirl)